# How to create HTML data attributes in Elm?

Tags: elm

I need to tag my Elm.Http elements with custom "data-*" attributes, for example:

```
<tr data-row="1">...</tr>
```

I have tried the following:

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Json.Encode as JsEncode

view ... =
  tr [ property "data-row" (JsEncode.string (toString 1)) ]
```

But this does nothing. Anyone know a way?

I think the problem is that Elm is actually setting JavaScript DOM attributes, so I really want to call element.dataset.row = "1" somehow.

The background is I need to expose some data to jQuery for my event handlers, because the Elm event library is missing a bunch of features I need, such as conditional preventDefault and form serialization. There are other ways to supply data via the DOM, but data-* attributes are by far the most straightforward.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use the [attribute](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/latest/Html-Attributes#attribute) function instead.

```
view ... =
    tr [ attribute "data-row" "1" ]
```

Comment: How do you add empty data tags?

Comment: If you're in a bit of puzzled or befuddlement between `attribute` vs `property`, might be worth checking out this: 
  - https://github.com/elm/html/blob/master/properties-vs-attributes.md